# SUM column in bookshelfjs relationship

Tags: node.js, orm

I want to sum a column in a Bookshelfjs relationship. I have my query set up as

```
return this.hasMany('MutualFundPortfolio').query().sum('balance');
```

But I am having this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentFk' of undefined` any body has any clue how solve this? It seems Bookshelf doesn't support `sum`

```
const moment = require('moment');

const Bookshelf = require('../bookshelf');

require('./wishlist');
require('./kyc');

require('./wallet');

const User = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    hasTimestamps: true,
    hidden: ['code', 'password'],
    toJSON(...args) {
        const attrs = Bookshelf.Model.prototype.toJSON.apply(this, args);
        attrs.created_at = moment(this.get('created_at')).add(1, 'hour').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        attrs.updated_at = moment(this.get('updated_at')).add(1, 'hour').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        return attrs;
    },
    local_wallet() {
        return this.hasMany('LocalWallet').query((qb) => {
            qb.orderBy('id', 'DESC').limit(1);
        });
    },
    mutual_fund_portfolio() {
        return this.hasMany('MutualFundPortfolio').query().sum('balance');
    },
    global_wallet() {
        return this.hasMany('GlobalWallet').query((qb) => {
            qb.orderBy('id', 'DESC').limit(1);
        });
    },
    local_gift_card_wallet() {
        return this.hasMany('LocalGiftCardWallet').query((qb) => {
            qb.orderBy('id', 'DESC').limit(1);
        });
    },
    global_gift_card_wallet() {
        return this.hasMany('GlobalGiftCardWallet').query((qb) => {
            qb.orderBy('id', 'DESC').limit(1);
        });
    }
});

module.exports = Bookshelf.model('User', User);
```

Above is the full user model. I am then getting the value as

```
return User.where({ id })
            .orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            .fetch({
                withRelated: [
                    'mutual_fund_portfolio',
                    'local_wallet',
                    'global_wallet',
                    'local_gift_card_wallet',
                    'global_gift_card_wallet'
                ]
            })
```

The `mutual_fund_portfolio` comes out as an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

[hasMany](https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Model-instance-hasMany) performs a simple SQL join on a key. I believe the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentFk' of undefined` error refers to the fact that the table you are referencing here `MutualFundPortfolio` does not share a key with the table in the model you are using here.

It's not visible above sample but I'm assuming it's something like:

```js
const User = bookshelf.model('User', {
  tableName: 'users',
  books() {
    return this.hasMany('MutualFundPortfolio').query().sum('balance');
  }
})
```

In my hypothetical example the `users` table has a primary key id column `userId` that is also in `MutualFundPortfolio` as a foreign key. My guess is that the error is because `MutualFundPortfolio` does not have that column/foreign key.

Comment: In my case, the foreign key in the many side table exists. It just can't associate aggregation with it. If I do sorting like Original Question, it works. But no aggregation works. Even if you run simple query like `return knex('wallets').sum('balance')`, it will raise the same `parentFk` error.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to integrate Sum and other aggregations in Bookshelf relations. The approach is to:

1. Define the normal relation in Model
2. Catch the relation call in Controller inside `withRelated` to get the query builder object, from which you select only the FK field and aggregate any other field, because by default it selects all fields and won't allow aggregation query.

In model, define relation:

```
mutual_fund_portfolio() {
    return this.hasMany('MutualFundPortfolio');
},
```

In controller, put an object with a key with the same name as the relation to catch it:

```
return User.where({ id })
  .orderBy('id', 'DESC')
  .fetch({
      withRelated: [
          'local_wallet',
          'global_wallet',
          'local_gift_card_wallet',
          'global_gift_card_wallet',
          {
              mutual_fund_portfolio: qb => {
                  // make sure to select FK field to reach related records
                  // and only that FK field to allow aggregation
                  // user_id or mutual_fund_portfolios.user_id if users table already have recursive relation
                  qb.select('user_id').sum('balance as balance');
              }
           }
      ]
  });
```

`balance as balance` is to get column name as `balance` and not `sum('balance')`.

The only drawback is that you will get the result as array (hasMany) with 1 object:

```
"mutual_fund_portfolio": [
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "balance": 8260
    }
]
```